# Cant solve reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, combobox

I'm trying desperately to get my code work. When each `ComboBox` has its value selected, the values should be divided and the result should get inserted into `TextBox`.

`ComboBoxes` --> `Körpergröße`, `Gewicht`

`TextBox` --> `BMI`

My Code:

```
private void Körpergröße_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     int value1, value2;
     if (Körpergröße.SelectedItem.ToString() != "Bitte auswählen..." && Gewicht.SelectedItem.ToString() != "Bitte auswählen...")
     {
         string a = Körpergröße.SelectedItem.ToString();
         string b = Gewicht.SelectedItem.ToString();
         value1 = Int32.Parse(a);
         value2 = Int32.Parse(b);
         fillTextBox(value1, value2);
     }
}

private void fillTextBox(int value1, int value2)
{          
     double result = value1 / value2;
     BMI.Text = result.ToString();
}

private void Gewicht_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     int value1, value2;
     if (Gewicht.SelectedItem.ToString() != "Bitte auswählen..." && Körpergröße.SelectedItem.ToString() != "Bitte auswählen...")
     {
          string a = Körpergröße.SelectedItem.ToString();
          string b = Gewicht.SelectedItem.ToString();
          value1 = Int32.Parse(a);
          value2 = Int32.Parse(b);
          fillTextBox(value1, value2);
     }
}
```

When I execute the Program, it always gives me the exception at the if-part of both.

I compare it with `Bitte auswählen...` in order to ensure that this is not selected in the `CombobBox`, but a value.

Gewicht-ComboBox

```
<ComboBox Margin="205,77,0,0" Name="Gewicht" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" Height="23"
     SelectionChanged="Gewicht_SelectionChanged">                       
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Bitte auswählen..." IsSelected="True" ></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="40"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="41"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="42"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Körpergröße-ComboBox

```
<ComboBox Margin="205,50,0,0" Name="Körpergröße" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" Height="23" SelectionChanged="Körpergröße_SelectionChanged" >
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Bitte auswählen..." IsSelected="True"  ></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="150" ></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="151"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="152"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I'm guessing `Gewicht.SelectedItem` or `Körpergröße.SelectedItem` is null

Comment: edited the post. how come that they can return null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way for checking the selected item of `combobox` is incorrect. It should be like this:

```
if (((Gewicht.SelectedItem) as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString() != "Bitte auswählen...")
```

Also it would be better to just skip the first item and then select the selected item like this:

```
if (Gewicht.SelectedIndex > 0 && Körpergröße.SelectedIndex > 0)
{
     string a = ((Körpergröße.SelectedItem) as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString();
     string b = ((Gewicht.SelectedItem) as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check following before parsing its value to String

```
Körpergröße.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

And

```
Gewicht.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

If both values is NOT NULL then you can Parse Them ToString()..

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. I edited my post and pasted my XAML code. Cant imagine why these should be null.

Comment: I see... maybe you should try to set Value of both combo boxes on Form load event...

Answer (score 0):

You are not making sure your combo boxes selected index is NOT -1 before you run all of that code.

The Code is the same so break it out like this:

```
private void CalculateValues()
{
        int value1, value2;
        if (Gewicht.SelectedItem.ToString() != "Bitte auswählen..." && Körpergröße.SelectedItem.ToString() != "Bitte auswählen...")
        {
            string a = Körpergröße.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string b = Gewicht.SelectedItem.ToString();

            value1 = Int32.Parse(a);
            value2 = Int32.Parse(b);
            fillTextBox(value1, value2);
        }
}


    private void Gewicht_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
if(Gewicht.SelectedIndex > -1 && Körpergröße.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
CalculateValues();
}
}

    private void Körpergröße_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
if(Körpergröße.SelectedIndex > -1 && Gewicht.SelectedIndex > -1 )
{
CalculateValues();
}
}
```

There is a better way to write that code (for example only updating a class level int value1 or value2 and then calling the CalculateValues() but the code as it is here should work. Notice in the Selected Index Changed event I am checking to make sure it is > - 1: SelectedIndex > -1 because on loading it gets set to -1. And has a change event fired .. and you have NOTHING in -1 index. NULL REFERENCE.

Comment: Gave me an Error, a return value at CalculateValues() was needed

Comment: @Sasa private void CalculateValues(){ ..code to do calculation}

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that

- when you are selecting "**Körpergröße**", the check for
  **Gewicht.SelectedItem.ToString() != "Bitte auswählen...** in your if block is giving the error as **Gewicht** combo is still not selected.
- when you are selecting "**Gewicht**", the check for
  **Körpergröße.SelectedItem.ToString() != "Bitte auswählen...** in your if block is giving the error as **Körpergröße** combo is still not selected.

To resolve try setting default values in your comboboxes at form initialization.

Hope this helps...